# btrfs won't run from cron

Tags: linux, cron, btrfs

I'm trying to set up a cron job to create a btrfs subvolume snapshot of my root partition. The command works perfectly if I run it from the command line, but nothing happens at the scheduled cron time. I've tried piping to `logger` and redirecting stdout/stderr to file, and not only is there no content, the file I'm logging to isn't even created.

The cron command I have is as follows:

```
0 0 * * * /sbin/btrfs subvolume snapshot / "/snapshots/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"
```

I've tried prefixing it with `/bin/bash`, but that makes no difference. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure that cron is running?  Check the output of `ls -l | grep cron` for something like /usr/bin/crond.  If your only process showing is `grep cron` or perhaps `grep --color=auto cron` then it isn't.  You'll need to start the `cron` server via whatever method it is your disto has for managing servers.  `service cron start` works on a number of popular distros.

Comment: Yes, cron is running, although `ls -l | grep cron` isn't the command to tell me that. `pgrep cron` returned a PID. I also added a job `* * * * * touch /root/foo`, which worked as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did figure out what was wrong with the cron entry, but I just wrote a shell script to create the snapshot and invoked that from cron instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
/sbin/btrfs subvolume snapshot / "/snapshots/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"
touch  "/snapshots/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"
find /snapshots/* -maxdepth 0 -mtime +6 | xargs -n 1 /sbin/btrfs subvolume delete
```